# Firebase passing Authentication between web pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i don't know how to share the authentication between my web. For example, i want to pass authentication to home page after user logged in in login.html.

What is the problem:

After user logged in in login.html, the authentication is created.

```
//login.html
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
}
```

However, i need to change location.href to home.html after user logged in.

```
//login.html
if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    location.href = "home.html";
}
```

So, what is the solution that keep the authentication when changing web page?

```
  //home.html
    if (user) {
        // 
    }else {
        // No user is signed in.
     }
```

**web/login.html <--> web/home.html**

Answer (score 2):

Firebase keeps track of the authentication state between pages by storing the session id in local storage.

The best way to ensure a smooth flow for you users is to [*monitor* the authentication state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). From that documentation:

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

> By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current user.

Comment: So I am getting the currentUser correctly on the login page, but when I try to call it the same way firebase.auth().currentUser.uid on the home page it comes up as null... not sure why?